# ComboBox displays DataRowView instead of actual values

Tags: c#, .net, excel, data-binding, vsto

I have a problem with the combobox, I tried to populate it from data that is in myExcel.xls file but it is displaying System.Data.DataRowView in the combobox instead of the actual values.Here is my code:

```
Application excelApp = new ApplicationClass();
string strWB = "myExcel.xls";
string strWBPath = "D:\\TEMP\\";

// Opening Excel file
Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(strWBPath + strWB, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;

int column = 0;
int row = 0;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Agent Name");

for (row = 2; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    for (column = 1; column <= range.Columns.Count; column++)
    {
        dr[column - 1] = (range.Cells[row, column] as Range).Value2.ToString();
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
workbook.Close(true, null, null);
excelApp.Quit();

//  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

comboBox1.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Sheet1";
comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: btw, use `System.IO.Path.Combine()` instead just strings containing path and file name concatenation

Answer (score 1):

Value2 is an Object. As such, ToString will return the default which is the name rather than the value. Try using "as string" rather than ".ToString".

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason not to bind comboBox1.DataSource to a list instead?  Something like:

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x["FirstName"].ToString()).ToList();
```